# ASUS RT-AC87U USB Server issue

Tags: networking, hard-drive, usb

i have a lot of issues with the file server options. 
And the USB 3.0 port does not work with my USB 3.0 harddisk. 
i am able to connect it to the USB 2.0 port

i would like to integrate my harddisk that is connected to my routers USB port to windows pc, i dont want  to be forced to use the AiCloud website. 
and ofc i want to  connect to it from different networks.

i want it to be like this 
My PC--Home   Network--Harddisk
My PC--Friend Network--Harddisk
and i want it to act like a harddisk that is connected throug USB (integrate it in windows)

-1. first i try with FTP. the issue here is that i can integrate the folder 
ftp://my-cloud-disk.asuscomm.com/ 
bout i cannot integrate this 
ftp://my-cloud-disk.asuscomm.com/1TB_-_USB_3.0/
and that is a problem for me. i want my harddisk to act  like it is connected directly to the PC from the USB  port of the PC. 
so i cannot use the FTP server for my needs

-2. second i try with Samba and this works very good bout 
i cannot connect to it from other networks (if i am at a friends house).

-3. and i tried to integrate it via the Aicloud link. i get this error 
"joint verification failed. The server's password has expired on the Domain Controller"

i have tried a lot of other things and i just cannot get it to work the way i like it to work. 
is it even possible to do what i want to do with this router ?. 
I just bought it a couple of days ago for 234 dollars. one of the reasons i got this router was the USB harddisk server options.
And i simply cannot do what i bought it for.

Comment: So what you are wanting is to have ftp so you can access from elsewhere and also have it show as a network drive at home?

Comment: No i want to use it as network Harddrive at home and other networks (at friends). like Dropbox

Comment: FTP is not good enough for me

Comment: Just vpn then? If that will not work for you, then what you want will not work with Asus wrt

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two features to get this working as you want

1. Setup a VPN server on the Asus as per [this FAQ](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/114892)
2. Enable SMB(Samba) sharing so it acts as a regular network share

When at a friends house just connect to your VPN then put your routers IP address into the file explorer address bar. You can save it as a favourite/shortcut for convenience.